# C++ string member construction

Tags: c++, string, constructor

How do I go about using the constructor for a member which is a string? Here is an example (which is wrong I realize)

```
class Filestring {
public:
    string      sFile;

    Filestring(const string &path)
    {
        ifstream filestream(path.c_str());
        // How can I use the constructor for the member sFile??
        // I know this is wrong, but this illustrates what I want to do.
        string sFile((istreambuf_iterator<char>(filestream)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    }
};
```

So basically I want to be able to use the member sFile's constructor without doing a string copy. Is there a way to achieve this through assignment?

Comment: Why are you so concerned with a string copy?  If you're reading from a file, the file I/O time is going to take the majority of your runtime.

Comment: Just to get clear on this? are you trying to initialize sFile with the contents of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can use is `string::assign`:

```
sFile.assign(istreambuf_iterator<char>(filestream), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

But in C++11 there is a move assignment operator for string so doing the following is almost as efficient (there is no copy of character data, the character data are moved):

```
sFile = string(istreambuf_iterator<char>(filestream), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Yet another trick when C++11 move assignment is not avaliable is to use `std::swap` or `string::swap`. The efficiency would be probably almost identical to the move assignment variant.

```
string newContent(istreambuf_iterator<char>(filestream), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
std::swap(sFile, newContent); // or sFile.swap(newContent);
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to make filestream a member, so it can be referred to in the constructor initialization list:

```
class Filestring {
private:
    ifstream filestream;
public:
    string      sFile;

    Filestring(const string &path) : filestream(path.c_str()), sFile((istreambuf_iterator<char>(filestream)), istreambuf_iterator<char>())
    {}
};
```

For this to work properly, filestream must appear in the class definition before sFile, or else it won't be initialized in time to use it in the sFile constructor.  Of course, you're also adding to the overhead of the Filestring class.

A safer technique which also avoids the overhead of string copying is to use string::swap():

```
class Filestring {
public:
    string      sFile;

    Filestring(const std::string &path)
    {
        std::ifstream filestream(path.c_str());
        sFile.swap(string((istreambuf_iterator<char>(filestream)), istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    }
};
```

Comment: Would swap be faster than `sFile = string(istreambuf_iterator<char>(filestream), istreambuf_iterator<char>());` ?

Comment: In your first example you can avoid the private `filestream` element if you construct it as a temporary within the initializer of `sFile`. That would avoid the order of elements requirement which appears error prone to me if the class grows and someone wants to tidy it up.

Comment: This is what I was going for (but didn't fully spell out) in my answer... +1

Answer (score 1):

Not really, you're bound to do a copy if you don't initialize members inside the initializer list, which in your case doesn't seem possible.

Note that your code doesn't initialize the member, but creates a new local variable.

The proper way would be

```
sFile = std::string((istreambuf_iterator<char>(filestream)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it.
But its not worth the extra complexity. If you want to avoid the cost of a copy (which a decent compiler will probably do anyway). You can load it into a temporary then use std::swap().

I would do:

```
class Filestring {
public:
    string      sFile;

    Filestring(const string &path)
    {
        ifstream filestream(path.c_str());
        string data((istreambuf_iterator<char>(filestream)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());

        // Just swap the internal data structures:
        std::swap(sFile, data);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use initialization lists:

```
Filestring(const string &path):sFile(/*what you're initializing with*/)
{//more
}
```

Comment: He's initializing it with the contents of a file, so the file needs to be opened before initializing `sFile`

Comment: @Prætorian True; however, wouldn't it be possible to do that before construction of the string (i.e. in the ctor of an earlier class member) and pass the contents from that object into the string ctor, all within the initializer list?

Comment: Not the way the class is currently implemented. If he were to make the `ifstream` a member variable *and declare it before* the `string` member variable (order is important) then you can open the file and construct the string in the `Filestring` constructor's initialization list. (BTW, I didn't downvote :-))

Comment: @Prætorian No worries, a couple of points here and there don't bother me. Though I didn't do the best job of fully spelling it out, what you are saying is what I was going for: "earlier member" = declared first. And the way he's implementing it doesn't work already, so alternative implementations are, I think, in order. My point wasn't that it was a good idea, just that it *could be done* - though I'll take my lumps for not clarifying further in my hurry to get back to work :/

Answer (score 0):

```
sFile.assign(constructor args);
```